# Why are my CSS animations only working when selecting the element in dev-tools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, css-animations

I have a table that is changing its height when it is clicked, but I want it to transition its height over 500ms when it is clicked. The problem is, my animations don't animate unless I highlight the 'nested-table' element in the Chrome developer tools in the elements tab. The dev-tools don't even see an animation happening unless that element is highlighted.

Here is my base CSS for the table:

```
.nested-table {
    display: none;
    min-width: 860px;
    max-height: 0;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

This makes sure the table is hidden when the page loads. After it is clicked, I add a "expand" class to the table's classlist. The "expand" CSS contains all the animation CSS.

Here is my animation CSS:

```
.expand { 
display: flex;
max-height: 2500px;
opacity: 1;

-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

This does cause the nested-table element to transition between being hidden and poping below its parent element, but only if I highlight the nested-table in the elements tab. Any reason as to why this is?

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I needed to use animations and keyframes instead of transition.

```
.nested-table {
    animation: change-height 500ms ease 1 forwards;
}
@keyframes change-height {
    0%{
        max-height: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
        max-height: 2500px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```